# Plugin alternative to wp-blog-header.php hacks?

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

I have 2 extra pieces of code in wp-blog-header.php.

The first handles 410 and 404 headers and goes at the top, before the line `if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {`

The second handles some complex redirects and goes after the `wp();` line.

I know it's a bad idea to hack core WP scripts (especially as my hacks get overwritten on most WP updates). I'd like to do both as plugins, but I can't figure out which hooks to use, nor how.

I've looked at a few existing plugins, but none do what I need.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You’re going to need to be specific about what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. Let's settle the first section of code first. It looks for unwanted things in the request's query string (the results of unsuccessful experiments like "modpagespeed" and "wp_touch"). It also looks for deleted articles using an array and returns a 410 header so the search engines no longer cache them. The plugin 410 for WP almost does what I want here, but doesn't. The only place I could get my code to work was  before the `if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {` line.

Comment: Can someone please help steer me in the right direction with this?

Comment: For anyone else who needs it, I solved it as follows via a plugin:
(1) The first block of code needed to be triggered with: `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'redirect_block' );`
(2) The second block involving redirects was originally after the `wp();` call, so in the plugin it is triggered as follows: `add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_old_style_urls' );`

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs it, I solved it as follows via a plugin:

(1) The first block of code needed to be triggered with: `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'redirect_block' );`

(2) The second block involving redirects was originally after the `wp();` call in wp-blog-header.php, so in the plugin it is triggered as follows: `add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_old_style_urls' );`